# C++ std::variant vs std::any

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant, stdany

C++17 presents [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), both able to store different type of values under an object. For me, they are somehow similar (are they?).

Also `std::variant` restricts the entry types, beside this one. Why we should prefer `std::variant` over `std::any` which is simpler to use?

Comment: `std::variant` only works with a predefined set of types, while `std::any` literally goes with _any type_. It totally depends on your use cases, which of them is the better choice.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: What are _predefined set of types_?

Comment: Roughly speaking, the first one is compile-time, the second one is run-time.

Comment: @deepmax The same what you expressed in your question stateing _"restricts the entry types"_.

Comment: std::variant is a template, std::any is not.

Comment: no `std::visit()` for `std::any`; this, IMHO, should be a valid reason to prefer `std::variant`, when possible.

Comment: It's like `void*` vs a union imo

Comment: See also: [C++ `std::any` vs `std::variant` vs `std::optional`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64479978/4561887)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

**The more things you check at compile time the fewer runtime bugs you have.**

`variant` guarantees that it contains one of a list of types (plus valueless by exception).  It provides a way for you to guarantee that code operating on it considers every case in the variant with `std::visit`; even every case for a *pair* of `variant`s (or more).

`any` does not.  With `any` the best you can do is "if the type isn't exactly what I ask for, some code won't run".

`variant` exists in automatic storage.  `any` may use the free store; this means `any` has performance and `noexcept(false)` issues that `variant` does not.

Checking for which of N types is in it is O(N) for an `any` -- for `variant` it is O(1).

`any` is a dressed-up `void*`.  `variant` is a dressed-up `union`.

`any` cannot store non-copy or non-move able types.  `variant` can.

The type of `variant` is documentation for the reader of your code.

Passing a `variant<Msg1, Msg2, Msg3>` through an API makes the operation obvious; passing an `any` there means understanding the API requires reliable documentation or reading the implementation source.

Anyone who has been frustrated by statically typeless languages will understand the dangers of `any`.

Now this doesn't mean `any` is bad; it just doesn't solve the same problems as `variant`.  As a copyable object for type erasure purposes, it can be great.  Runtime dynamic typing has its place; but that place is not "everywhere" but rather "where you cannot avoid it".

Comment: Great explanation in one phrase: "any is a dressed-up void*. variant is a dressed-up union".

Answer (score 10):

The difference is that the objects are stored within the memory allocated by `std::variant`:

[cppreference.com - std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

> As with unions, if a variant holds a value of some object type `T`,  **the object representation of `T` is allocated directly within the object representation of the variant itself. Variant is not allowed to allocate additional (dynamic) memory**.

and for `std::any` this is not possible.

As of that a `std::variant`, does only require one memory allocation for the `std::variant` itself, and it can stay on the stack.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to never using additional heap memory, `variant` has one other advantage:

You can `std::visit` a `variant`, but not `any`.