# "std::any" vs "std::variant" vs "std::optional"

Tags: c++

I know there is a question about `std::any` vs `std::variant` (see [C++ `std::variant` vs `std::any`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56303939/4561887)), but `std::optional` is also about the same thing.

What are the differences and use-cases of each?

Comment: `std::optional` only stores one type, `std::variant` stores several types, `std::any` stores any type, no need to specify it upfront. These are different structures for different needs.

Answer (score 19):

I have a very general rule:

Every time you want to use a `union` use `std::variant`.

Every time you want to use a `void*` use `std::any`.

Every time you want to return `nullptr` as an indication of an error use `std::optional`.

Comment: Good, but I consider there are also non-error usecases for optional, e.g. when looking (find) if a certain object exists in a collection, returning the object is found and nullopt when not.

Comment: My rule is similar, with the alteration of:  every time you want to return `nullptr` as an indication of an error (and exceptions are inappropriate) use `std::variant<Foo*, ErrorCode>` for a non-owning pointer, or `std::variant<std::unique_ptr<Foo>, ErrorCode>` for an owning pointer.

Comment: Sure there are exceptions to this rule. It is very general, but works as a good example for guys with pre-C++11 and pure C background (including myself). I deliberately made the answer short - to pick out the differences in their purpose ans usage.

Comment: @JHBonarius I'd return a raw pointer in that case, as you often want a reference not a copy

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, `boost:optional` allows `T&` but `std::optional` doesn't. I use `std::reference_wrapper` to overcome that.