# Set template return type inside the function

Tags: c++, types

I have this system for some basic code reflection with selected types

```
        enum class PropType
    {
        BOOL = 0,
        INT,
        FLOAT,
        VEC2D,
        VEC3D
    };
    
    struct ScriptProp
    {
        std::string m_name;
        PropType m_type;
        void* m_Value;
    };
static auto* GetPropValue(const ScriptProp& prop)
{
    switch (prop.m_type)
    {
    case PropType::BOOL:
    {
        return (bool*)prop.m_Value;
    }
    case PropType::INT:
    {
        return (int*)prop.m_Value;
    }
    case PropType::FLOAT:
    {
        return (float*)prop.m_Value;
    }
    case PropType::VEC2D:
    {
        return (vec2d*)prop.m_Value;
    }
    case PropType::VEC3D:
    {
        return (vec3d*)prop.m_Value;
    }
    }
}
```

I want "GetPropValue" return with the correct deduced typename, maybe theres a way with templates?

Comment: `auto` is not a variant class, nor a dynamic object. It serves just to save you from typing when everyone, including the compiler, knows exactly what the concrete type is. You could potentially use [`any` or `variant`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56303939/69809), but it's 99% likely that your design is problematic. What you are doing here is basically `std::any_cast`.

Comment: op> Ever heard of [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)? Not for the return type, but directly in your struct, instead of m_type and m_value.

Comment: I think we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: a function must have one return type. What are you actually trying to achieve? It seems like your `GetPropValue` is nothing but a cast. And your actual issue is to map between the  runtime `prop` and a compile-time type. Such mapping is possible, just not via the return type of one function

Comment: How are you calling the function? Is the parameter `prop` really only known until runtime?

Comment: i need it to work like this : vec2d* value= GetPropValue(property)

Comment: this is the part I could have guessed, what is missing is: Where is `property` coming from? Why is it not possible to call it like this `vec2d* value = GetPropValue<vec2d>(property);` ? I mean if the caller has to know the return type anyhow (statically), why is it required that the function handles it dynamcially?

Comment: yeah I should just do `vec2d* value = GetPropValue<vec2d>(property);`.