# template parameter (either 1 or 2): any way to set it at runtime (compile-time if,...)?

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

template <unsigned int dim>
class MyClass
{
    public:
    private:
        double data[dim]; 
        //many more members that depend on dim
};

int main()
{
    std::fstream myfile("path_to_my_file.txt", std::ios_base::in);

    unsigned int dim;

    myfile >> dim; //depending on the file content, dim=1 or dim=2

    std::shared_ptr<MyClass<dim>> ptr;

    
}
```

I have a pointer to a class with template parameter `dim` (an integer)
In my case, `dim` is either `1` or `2`.

I know that template parameters must be known at compile time. But, is there a way to tell the compiler to compile both `MyClass<1>` and `MyClass<2>` and choose the desired class at runtime?

Comment: Show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also see [C++ std::variant vs std::any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303939/c-stdvariant-vs-stdany)

Comment: [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?

Comment: The templates are irrelevant to the problem. You are looking for a factory function, or polymorphism or both.

Comment: @NathanPierson How could that look like using std::variant?

Comment: Yes, use an if statement. Not really seeing the problem, though maybe the real problem is not stated.

Comment: @john The issue is that I read dim from file at runtime

Comment: In some scenarios you may want your template class to extends some base type with a virtual destructor (and possibly some virtual functions) and use `std::shared_ptr<my_class_base>`, but without knowing the details of `my_class` or how it's used we won't be able to provide good advice here...

Comment: @Simon But an if statement can make a decision based on a value read from a file at run time. My guess is that your real question is that after you have created the object with the appropriate dimension do you then handle that object with the same code as if you had created the other object. That's a question that is hard to answer without more context,

Comment: @john I provided a minimal example that approximately illustrates what I want to do

Comment: @Jason You pointed out to std::variant. Is that appropriate in my scenario? (see the updated question)

Comment: @Simon, your example still lacks the usage. As in, it doesn't give an example of what the client code looks like. What is the code that _uses_ `MyClass` like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the question if still hard to answer, but I'll present a possible solution based on *polymorphism*. A template based solution might also be possible but the choice between these two is hard to judge given the lack of context.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {};
    virtual void something() = 0;
    // more pure virtual methods
};

template <unsigned int dim>
class MyClass : public Base
{
public:
    void something() override;
    // overrides for other pure virtual methods
private:
    double data[dim]; 
    //many more members that depend on dim
};


int main()
{
    int dim = ,,,;

    shared_ptr<Base> ptr;
    if (dim == 1)
        ptr = make_shared<MyClass<1>>();
    else
        ptr = make_shared<MyClass<2>>();
    ptr->something();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try. Could you please show the way using std::variant? Because MyClass actually is an somehow independent class and it would not really be neccessary to associate a base class with it.

Comment: A tutorial on how to use `std::variant` is a bit beyond me. I guess you can find something on the internet.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.cppstories.com/2018/06/variant/) for instance.

Comment: I have not seen std::variant in this context so far. If it were not a big deal for you, I would appreciate if you would extend your answer.

Comment: `std::variant<std::shared_ptr<MyClass<1>>, std::shared_ptr<MyClass<2>>> ptr;`. At some point you will have to learn how to research things by yourself, instead of being shown them. Now seems like a good time..

Comment: You are right. I should try to manage this by myself. Thanks!

Comment: To get the used variant hold by ptr, std::get<0>(ptr) and std::get<1>(ptr) works fine. The problem is that I have to wrap this in an if-statement since ptr.index() is not a compile-time constant, hence std::get<ptr.index()>(ptr) clearly does not work. Is there a way to get the index without having to use std::get?

Comment: I thought it is better to ask this in a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76074067/c-getting-the-held-index-of-a-variant-without-using-stdget

Answer (score 3):

Your example is not sufficient to give a correct answer. If there is no assumption on `my_class<t>`, `std::shared_ptr<my_class<1>>` and `std::shared_ptr<my_class<2>>` are totally unrelated types, thus if your goal is to write something like:

```
int Dim;
... // set Dim at runtime
std::shared_ptr<my_class<Dim>> p;
```

then you will need to use a union-like type (such as a plain `union` or `std::variant` or whatever) which, IMHO, is not a good idea.

The other use case I can imagine is that you will call a template function instantiated with the desired type. In this case, you can write a simple `switch`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
template<typename T> void foo();
...
int Dim;
...
switch (Dim)
{
    case 1:
    {
        foo<std::shared_ptr<my_class<1>>();
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        foo<std::shared_ptr<my_class<2>>();
        break;
    }
}
```